New record for minimally clued 7x7 Hidato (now with 6 clues!)
Rule of Hidato:

Fill the grid with consecutive numbers such that they connect orthogonally and diagonally.

Solve the following three Hidato puzzles.
8 clues

7 clues

6 clues

You can solve these on Penpa: 8 clues, 7 clues, 6 clues.

Is this a race to the bottom? I solved the 8- and 7-clue puzzles before you edited to make the 6-clue one. (Edit: I also added a solve path for the 6-clue)
8-clue solution

 

7-clue solution

 

6-clue solution
See mathlander's solution.
Solve path (8-clue)

 Trivial deductions:
 


 This is the only way to escape the bottom-right after 17-20:
 

Then the solution follows.
Solve path (7-clue)

 Trivial deductions:
 


 There is a risk of cutting off the top-right with the 1-7 path, so I speculated that there must be a two-way path to the top-right (I believed that the ending of 39-49 couldn't possibly finish in the top-right). So the only way is this:
 


 The 19-25 forces the following. And continuing with the assumption of the two-way travel to the top right:
 

Then the solution follows.
Solve path (6-clue)

 Trivial deductions
 

Notation: (i, j) = i-th row, j-th column.

 Now (1, 2) can either be 49 or 8. It cannot be 8 because it forces the following and breaks 22-26.
 


 So it is 49 and gives the following:
 


 13 cannot be in (5, 6) because it either cuts off 1-9 or isolates (5, 7), but the 49 is already placed. So 13 is in (5, 7), and we have:
 


 To have 33-47, I must leave a two-way path in each of the top-right and bottom-left. This is the only way to do it. (This reminds us of the second step in the 7-clue puzzle)
 

Then the solution follows.

Sorry about the edit. I didn't expect I would find the 6-clue puzzle so soon, and I didn't feel like posting a separate puzzle for that.

No problem! Thank you for the nice puzzles :)

In the 6-clue puzzle, I am not clear on why the 13 must go where you put it as an "obvious" deduction. It seems to me it could be 1 to the left (at that stage) and still connect.

@MatthieuM. Thank you for noticing it. I must have gone back and forth in my solve and took screenshots at inconsistent times. I have now fixed the solve path to be more logical.

Here is an image with the solution to the 6 clue puzzle:

 


Whoa you beat me by 39 seconds but luckily we solved different puzzles. Seeing this, I'll work on writing out my solve paths instead of re-doing your solution.
